# How do I change a value within a variable based on the value of another variable in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, recode, demographics

I am trying to recode demographic variables. If the variable `Q36` equals `Other` and the variable `Q35` equals `Yes`, I want `Other` (from `Q36`) to be changed to `Hispanic`. If the variable `Q36` equals `Other` and the variable `Q35` equals `No`, I want `Other` (from `Q36`) to be changed to `Unspecified`.

Here's my code so far.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(Q36 = case_when(Q35 == "Yes" & Q36 == "Other" ~ Q36 == "Hispanic", 
Q35 == "No" & Q36 == "Other" ~ Q36 == "Unspecified")) -> data
```

Comment: On the right hand side of `~`, just provide the value (like `~"Hispanic"`), rather than `~Q36=="Hispanic"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(Q36 = case_when(Q35 == "Yes" & Q36 == "Other" ~ "Hispanic", 
                 Q35 == "No" & Q36 == "Other" ~ "Unspecified",
                TRUE~Q36))
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help. The only other thing I had to do to complete it was to add {-> data} as seen below:


```
data %>% 
  mutate(Q36 = case_when(Q35 == "Yes" & Q36 == "Other" ~ "Hispanic", 
                 Q35 == "No" & Q36 == "Other" ~ "Unspecified",
                TRUE~Q36)) -> data
```